How to use the class method as reference
We have this class
class Fruit {
  public $name;
  public $color;

  function set_name($name) {
    $this->name = $name;

    //ISSUE:
    //We are using a PHP library that accepts a callback function as parameter
    new BlaBlaLibrary($this->some_callback);
            
  }

  function some_callback() {
    ......
  }
}

$f = new Fruit();
$f->set_name("apple");

As you can see, we are using a PHP library that is accepting a callback function as parameter. We want to do this but doesnt work:
new BlaBlaLibrary($this->some_callback);

This one works just fine though:
new BlaBlaLibrary(function(){
    ....
});

Question: How can we pass the function of the class and not an anonymous function?
Thanks in advance.

Could you give an example of what you are trying to reach exactly?

You can use
new BlaBlaLibrary([$this, 'some_callback']);


This array tells PHP that you want to use the some_callback method of the current object ($this) as the callback


make sure some_callback defined as public

